# Need to update historical Record for status changed date in Case

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

Below are my scenarios need to achieve in an anonymous script.

I have created 5 fields (`ClosedDate__c`, `NewStatusDate__c`, `EscalateDate__c`, `InProgressDate` and `OnHoldDate__c`). In my instance, I have more 2000 records. I want to just track when each status has been the change for those 2000 records.

Say for the example:

I have record changed **New** to **In Progress** 4 weeks back. After 2 weeks, it has been changed to **On hold**.Today I changed the status to **Closed**. There will be History tracking in Case detail page. I want to populate those date to appropriate fields based on status history.

Here I did some workarounds:

```
 List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
    List<CaseHistory> CaseHistoryList = new List<CaseHistory>();
    Map<Id, Date> caseIdMap  = new Map<Id, Date>();
    //Querying Case Records here
    for(Case cs: [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case]){
        caseList.add(cs);
    }
    if(caseList.size() > 0){
       //Querying history for Case
       CaseHistoryList = [SELECT newValue, createdDate, OldValue, CaseId FROM CaseHistory WHERE CaseID IN :caseList AND Field = 'Status'];
        System.debug('CaseHistoryList: '+CaseHistoryList);
        if(CaseHistoryList.size() > 0){
            for(CaseHistory csHis : CaseHistoryList){
                if(csHis.newValue == 'New'){
                    caseIdMap.put(csHis.caseId, csHis.CreatedDate.date());
                    System.debug('CaseHistory Map: '+caseIdMap);
                }
            }
        }
        if(caseIdMap.size() > 0){
            for(Case updateCase : [SELECT Id, ClosedDate__c, NewStatusDate__c, EscalateDate__c, InProgressDate, OnHoldDate__c Status FROM Case WHERE ID in :caseIdMap.keyset()]){
               //Need to populate date field for each status.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut this down quite a bit, that is if I understand your requirements correctly, just use `Maps`.. I recommend putting a limiter on this, 2000 is a lot of records, meaning you should be passing something into the first `for` query to only select certain cases.. I just reread this and you want to do this for an execute anon script and I don't know thing that is the route you should go or at least do this in a QA environment first.  I would then create `batch` apex to handle this in the future

```
Map<ID, Case> caseMap = new Map<ID, Case>();

for(Case cs: [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case])
{
    caseMap.put(cs.ID, cs);
}

if(caseMap.size() > 0)
{
    for(CaseHistory caseHistory :  [SELECT newValue, createdDate, OldValue, CaseId FROM CaseHistory WHERE CaseID IN : caseMap.keySet() AND Field = 'Status'])
    {
        if(caseHistory.newValue == 'New' && caseMap.containsKey(caseHistory.CaseID))
        {
            /*caseMap.get(caseHistory.CaseID).ClosedDate__c = caseHistory.???
            caseMap.get(caseHistory.CaseID).NewStatusDate__c = .
            caseMap.get(caseHistory.CaseID).EscalateDate__c
            caseMap.get(caseHistory.CaseID).InProgressDate
            caseMap.get(caseHistory.CaseID).OnHoldDate__c
            caseMap.get(caseHistory.CaseID).Status*/
        }
    }

  update caseMap.values();
}
```

Comment: Hey @EricSSH, Thanks for your reply. All workarounds are going on Dev Sandbox only. There is three more sandboxes environment to test this requirement before moving to production. Seems like it will work.   I will test this and let you know. Again, Thanks for your help.